# Use module from parent directory in rust

Tags: module, rust

Is it possible to structure a rust project in this way?

Directory structure:

```
src
├── a
│   └── bin1.rs
├── b
│   ├── bin2.rs
└── common
    ├── mod.rs
```

from Cargo.toml:

```
[[bin]]
name = "bin1"
path = "src/a/bin1.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "bin2"
path = "src/b/bin2.rs"
```

I would like to be able to use the `common` module in `bin1.rs` and `bin2.rs`. It's possible by adding the path attribute before the import:

```
#[path="../common/mod.rs"]
mod code;
```

Is there a way for `bin1.rs` and `bin2.rs` to use `common` without having to hardcode the path?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The recommended method to share code between binaries is to have a `src/lib.rs` file. Both binaries automatically have access to anything accessible through this `lib.rs` file as a separate crate.

Then you would simply define a `mod common;` in the `src/lib.rs` file. If your crate is called `my_crate`, your binaries would be able to use it with

```
use my_crate::common::Foo;
```

Comment: This helped me enormously. I have also seen something like `use crate:: ...` which I thought might refer to "whatever the root crate is" but that returns a compiler error "no X in the root" (where X is my module name). What is the "root" crate, then?

Comment: You should think of `lib.rs` and `main.rs` as the roots of two entirely distinct crates. When accessing something inside the same crate, you use `use crate::`, and when accessing something in `lib.rs` from `main.rs`, you use `use my_crate::`. There is no way to access something from `main.rs` in the `lib.rs` crate.

Comment: Where is the 'my_crate' name determined? The name in cargo.toml?

Comment: Yes, it's taken from your `Cargo.toml`.