# could not find `schema` in `super` when import rust mod

Tags: rust

I am learning rust, now tried to import a struct, this is the source file path `app_root/src/model/response/playlist_response.rs`, I am import another struct like this:

```
#[path = "../../models.rs"]
mod models;

use models::QueryPlaylist;
```

the `model.rs` path is `app_root/src/models.rs`, the `models.rs` file look like this:

```
use super::schema::posts;
use super::schema::playing_record;
use super::schema::favorites;
use super::schema::songs;
use super::schema::playlist;
use super::schema::album;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Insertable,Serialize,Queryable)]
#[table_name="playlist"]
pub struct QueryPlaylist {
    pub id: i64,
    pub creator: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub cover_url: Option<String>,
    pub description: Option<String>,
    pub subscribed: Option<i32>,
    pub subscribed_count: Option<i64>,
    pub comment_count: Option<i64>,
    pub share_count: Option<i32>,
    pub play_count: Option<i32>
}
```

when I compile the project, shows error like this:

```
$ cargo build                                                                                                                                        ‹ruby-2.7.2›
   Compiling reddwarf_music v0.1.0 (/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf_music)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::schema`
 --> src/biz/music/../../model/response/../../models.rs:1:12
  |
1 | use super::schema::posts;
  |            ^^^^^^ could not find `schema` in `super`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::schema`
 --> src/biz/music/../../model/response/../../models.rs:2:12
  |
2 | use super::schema::playing_record;
  |            ^^^^^^ could not find `schema` in `super`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::schema`
 --> src/biz/music/../../model/response/../../models.rs:3:12
  |
3 | use super::schema::favorites;
  |            ^^^^^^ could not find `schema` in `super`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::schema`
 --> src/biz/music/../../model/response/../../models.rs:4:12
  |
4 | use super::schema::songs;
  |            ^^^^^^ could not find `schema` in `super`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::schema`
 --> src/biz/music/../../model/response/../../models.rs:5:12
  |
5 | use super::schema::playlist;
  |            ^^^^^^ could not find `schema` in `super`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::schema`
 --> src/biz/music/../../model/response/../../models.rs:6:12
  |
6 | use super::schema::album;
  |            ^^^^^^ could not find `schema` in `super`
```

the `schema.rs` file path is `app_root/src/schema.rs`. I am import using the wrong way? what is the problem like this way? what should I do to make it work? This is the `main.rs`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

// #[macro_use]
// extern crate redis;

#[path="biz/music/music.rs"] mod music;
#[path="config/db/config.rs"] mod config;
#[path="biz/music/songs.rs"] mod songs;
#[path="biz/music/test.rs"] mod test;
#[path="biz/user/user.rs"] mod user;
#[path="biz/music/playlist.rs"] mod playlist;


#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/music/music", routes![music::play_record,music::save_play_record,music::like,music::dislike])
        .mount("/music/songs",routes![songs::detail])
        .mount("/music/user",routes![user::recent_found])
        .mount("/music/playlist",routes![playlist::user_playlist])
        .mount("/music/test", routes![test::detail])
}
```

Comment: do you have `src/models.rs` and `src/schema.rs` imported or declared in `main.rs` as `mod models;` and `mod schema;`?

Comment: yes, I have imported the `models.rs` and `schema.rs` to `main.rs` as mod. @kmdreko

Comment: I have pasted my `main.rs` @kmdreko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `#[path = ...]` to try to import `models.rs`. It will declare a *new module* instead of using it as declared in `main.rs`. This in turn messes up how *it* imports stuff since `super` doesn't mean the same thing.

Instead you should simply import it using:

```
use crate::models;
```

See also:

- [Use module from parent directory in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912236/use-module-from-parent-directory-in-rust)
- [Why do I get "expected struct file1::A found struct file2::A" error when using a struct in multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928911/why-do-i-get-expected-struct-file1a-found-struct-file2a-error-when-using-a)
- [Clear explanation of Rust’s module system](http://www.sheshbabu.com/posts/rust-module-system/)

Comment: I get error no `models` in the root when using use directly import mod.@kmdreko

Comment: Please include `main.rs` in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is how you work with different files in your project:
Say you have this structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── some_logic.rs
├── database
│   ├── models.rs
├── config.rs
└── main.rs
```

In `main.rs` you declare:

```
mod config;
mod database{
    pub mod models;
}
mod app {
    pub mod some_logic;
}
```

Then you can use any public member of i.e. `models.rs` with: `database::models::SomeStruct`.
Same goes for `some_logic.rs` whose members you access with `app::some_logic::SomeStruct`. Of course `config.rs`'s members are simply accessed with `config::SomeStruct`.

Say you want to access a constant `MY_CONSTANT` withing `main.rs` from `models.rs`:

```
fn function_within_models_rs() {
    println!("Constant: {}", crate::MY_CONSTANT)
}
```

And accessing `pub const LOGIC_CONSTANT: i32 = 222;` declared in `some_logic.rs` from within `models.rs`:

```
fn function_within_models_rs() {
    println!("Constant: {}", crate::app::some_logic::LOGIC_CONSTANT)
}
```

As you see, elements that are accessed from outside of the module there are declared in, need to be declared as `pub` (public). The compiler is great in giving you hints about what needs to be set to public so I would suggest keeping things private until you really want to use them somewhere else.